# PWA still showing A2HS popup after install

Tags: iis, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

I have a Progressive Web Application which working fine (can be installed and working offline) on Server 1. We made a new server for testing (Server 2), however the PWA cannot be installed properly here. The A2HS popup shows up, installing seems fine, but the icon has a chrome badge at bottom right, and it is not sowing up in the settings/applications list. Reloading the page causes the A2HS popup again, making new icons next to the old ones.

There are three problems I can though at this moment:

- Server 1 has normal URL (https://server1/pwa), but Server 2 uses up
  address (https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx/pwa).
- Accessing Server 2 from mobile shows a warning at
  application/Manifest: “some of the icons could not be loaded”. The
  icons from the path can be loaded manually.  It resolved 200 both
  ways, according to the IIS logs. This warning only shows up on
  mobile, desktop version works fine. The mobile is connecting through
  4G/VPN. The connection is fast, and the icons are less than 40kb
- Some IIS configuration mismatch, but I don't remember configuration
  about the PWA, it worked out of the box.

Lighthouse shows perfect score. Everything is checked.

My goal is to install the app properly, so it only shows the A2HS once, and install the app to settings/applications.

Comment: A PWA is installed in each user's browser on only their device or desktop. You are connecting to these servers via remote access in some way and using the browser on that server?

Comment: @Mathias On mobile phone, I am connecting over 4G/VPN and using the mobile's chrome to access the PWA. On desktop, I'm accessing a PC on the server's network with RDP.

Comment: So on your mobile device (Android?), you are accessing an HTTPS URL to get to a website that is a PWA? And there each time you visit you are asked to install and it installs a second ICON? Do this always happen to someone else on a device that has never visited that HTTPS URL?

Comment: Are you sure you have totally cleared out the browsers cache for and previous installations done while testing?

Comment: @Mathias I'm opening the site with HTTPS URL on Android device (Galaxy A5). Each time it want me to pin to startup, even if its there. Unfortunately, this is the only one mobile test device I have. The users cannot use the site until I fix the problem. I cleared the cache with develeoper console over remote debug (Application/clear storage/clear site data, clear history). The device works with Server 1 URL

Comment: So you can install multiple times and see multiple icons on your android device when looking at all applications?

Comment: If installing in Chrome on a server/desktop are you uninstalling by entering this into the browser's URL and right clicking to delete the app?   chrome://apps/

Comment: @Mathias Yes, on android, I can istall it multiple times. On desktop, I can only install once, the "install app" changes to "open is app". Uninstalling works with chrome://apps/, but how is it connected to the mobile version?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you are asking about the desktop being connected to the mobile. Each user installs the PWA in their browser on their device/laptop if they are using their browser to access the URL of your PWA.